# how to set cookie in kohana framework

Tags: php, cookies, kohana

I am trying to set and get a cookie in kohana framework, but I don't know how to call the class cookie in my controller.

```
<?php
class Landing_Page_Controller extends Controller {
  public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
       setcookie("kohanaSalt", "testKohanadata" , time()+3600);
    }
}
?>
```

The above is a simple way to set a cookie from php, but I want to set this cookie into session and do so using kohana, if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Landing_Page_Controller::index();
```

Comment: you mean add this to in my index action

Comment: this means you are calling the index() function inside the Landing_Page_Controller class